# csvデータから特定の項目を抽出し、Gmailの本文（message）に入れて送信するにはどうしたらいいですか？

Tags: python, google-api, gmail

そもそもやりたいことに対してコードが違っているかもしれませんが、
イメージは下記の通りです。

csvデータのイメージ
name,age,sex,tel,...

```
with open('sample.csv') as f: #cscファイルを指定
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    data = row[0] + row[3] #csvから特定の項目(nameとtel)をdataに代入
```

これだと1行分のデータしか入らないですよね？
100行あれば100行分のrow[0] + row[3]をすべて抽出してdataに代入したいです。
そして、dataに代入された値をgmailの本文にのせたい。

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

account = "hogehoge@gmail.com"
password = "passpass"


to_email = "送信先@hoge.com"
from_email = "送信元@gmail.com"


subject = "テストメール"
message = "テストメール" #←ここにdataを入れたい
msg = MIMEText(message, "html")
msg["Subject"] = subject
msg["To"] = to_email
msg["From"] = from_email


server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(account, password)
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: 「1行分を1通ずつ」ではなく、「CSVのデータすべてをまとめて1通」で送りたいということでしょうか？

Comment: CSVから必要な項目を抽出して、抽出したすべてをまとめて1通で送りたいです。

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じで、いったん各行をリストとして追加した後で、連結すれば良いでしょう。
必要ならば`encoding`の指定や変換とか、`row[3]`が無い時の対処などもやっておいてください。

```
data = []
with open('sample.csv') as f: #cscファイルを指定
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row[0] + row[3]) #csvから特定の項目(nameとtel)をdataに追加

message = '\n'.join(data) #dataのlistを改行で連結
```

Comment: messageに抽出したデータをいれることができましたが、改行がされず表示されてしまいます。

Comment: 送信するメールの属性がHTML形式になっているのでは？　TEXT形式にするか、'\n' の部分を '<br>' または '&lt;br&gt;' に変えてみてください。

Comment: メールの属性が"html"になっていました。"plain"に変更したら解決しました。ありがとうございます。